# Three.js html file do not show in "Web Browser" inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to use Eclipse for a Three.js project. One feature I expect from Eclipse is direct preview of the html file using three.js library.

My problem is that the project shows well in Firefox, but the page remains blank in the built-in "Web Browser" in Eclipse.

Edit: I found that it is possible to define Firefox as the default web browser (menu "Window", "Web Browser", "2 Firefox"), but this simply opens the file in Firefox, outside of Eclipse, this is not what I dreamt of :(

Comment: Because Eclipse is already mind-numbingly slow and bloated, why not add more useless features?

Comment: Don't use Eclipse's Web Browser to test stuff that involves JavaScript. EWB is designed as something for quickly taking a look at online documentation (primarily Javadocs) and has **absolutely** no JS support - to the point of refusing to run [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [dorukayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6304349/dorukayhan), you confirm the fact that Eclipse is not relevant for internal viewing of html files using javascript, like three.js.

As a consequence, I abandon Eclipse and move to [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), as [advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144165/which-development-environment-for-three-js-webgl-and-html5).